# Помогите нарисовать данный рисунок с помощью turtle

Tags: python, циклы, графика, turtle

Нужно нарисовать подобие следующего рисунка с помощью модуля turtle:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По-видимому, у меня проблемы с пространственным мышлением, поэтому код просто зацикливается, хотя, по моей идее, он должен прокручиваться

```
from turtle import*
from math import* 
speed(10)
down()
fd(200);bk(400);
goto(0,0);
left(90);
fd(200);bk(400);
goto(0,0);
stamp();
right(180);
a=50;
l=25;
circle(a);
goto(0,0);
l=25
for t in range(0,360):
 t=t+0.1
 r=a*cos(pi)+l
 circle(r,t)
mainloop()
```

Я понимаю, что проблема находится в цикле, но я не знаю, как ее преодолеть. объясните, пожалуйста, проблему.

Comment: Так делать нельзя ```for t in range(0,360): t=t+0.1```(изменять внутри цикла итерируемую переменную)

Comment: я понимаю, у меня нужное было под решеткой. Изначально я задала, чтобы t менялось до 2pi, пытаясь поменять величину радиуса, но и это не помогло

Comment: circle в цикле нарисует 360 кругов, пробуй там dot или pen.up pen.down. Вообще требуемые фигуры не стандартны то есть это не круги и не овалы, оптимальнее было бы рисование точками при исспользовании формулы и проходом по x,y